# How to prevent dublicated items in mongoDB when an item is updated

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

I am creating a multi-user dictionary, where several users can add words. I don't want that the same word could have dublicates. I was able to prevent dublicates when a word is added, but struggle with a functionality to prevent dublicates when a word is updated. For example, there is a word "apple" in a database, let's imagine someone wanted to update a word "apply" and accidentally wrote "apple", in such a case, updated word "apple" should not go to database, since there is already such word there. Please help me.

**Words API**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Word = require('../../models/Word');
const validateWordInput = require('../../validation/word');
const passport = require('passport');

// @route  GET api/words/test
// @desc   tests words route
// @access Public
router.get('/test', (req, res) => res.json({ msg: 'Words works' }));

// @route  POST api/words
// @desc   Add words to profile
// @access Private
router.post(
  '/',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const { errors, isValid } = validateWordInput(req.body);

    // Check validation
    if (!isValid) {
      // Return any errors
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }

    Word.find({}).then(word => {
      if (
        word.filter(
          wrd =>
            wrd.ugrWordCyr.toString().toLowerCase() ===
            req.body.ugrWordCyr.toLowerCase()
        ).length !== 0
      ) {
        return res
          .status(404)
          .json({ wordalreadyexists: 'Word already exists' });
      } else {
        const newWord = new Word({
          user: req.user.id,
          ugrWordCyr: req.body.ugrWordCyr,
          rusTranslation: req.body.rusTranslation,
          example: req.body.example,
          exampleTranslation: req.body.exampleTranslation,
          origin: req.body.origin,
          sphere: req.body.sphere,
          lexis: req.body.lexis,
          grammar: req.body.grammar,
          partOfSpeech: req.body.partOfSpeech,
          style: req.body.style
        });

        newWord.save().then(word => res.json(word));
      }
    });
  }
);

// @route  Put api/words/:id
// @desc   Update a word by id
// @access Private

router.put(
  '/:id',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const { errors, isValid } = validateWordInput(req.body);

    // Check validation
    if (!isValid) {
      // Return any errors
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }

    Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id }).then(profile => {
      Word.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(word => {
          // Check for word owner
          if (word.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
            return res
              .status(401)
              .json({ notauthorized: 'User not authorized' });
          }

          const wordID = req.params.id;
          const wordInput = req.body;

          // Update
          Word.findByIdAndUpdate(
            { _id: wordID },
            { $set: wordInput },
            { returnOriginal: false },
            (err, word) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
            }
          ).then(word => {
            res.json(word);
          });
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nowordfound: 'No word found' }));
    });
  }
);

// @route  GET api/words
// @desc   Dislay all words
// @access Public
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Word.find()
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then(words => res.json(words))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nonwordsfound: 'No words found' }));
});

//@route  Get api/words/:id
//@desc   Get word by id
//@access Public
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Word.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(word => res.json(word))
    .catch(err =>
      res.status(404).json({ nonwordfound: 'No word found with that ID' })
    );
});

//@route  DELETE api/words/:id
//@desc   DELETE word
//@access Private

router.delete(
  '/:id',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id }).then(profile => {
      Word.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(word => {
          // Check for post owner
          if (word.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
            return res
              .status(401)
              .json({ notauthorized: 'User not authorized' });
          }

          // Delete
          word.remove().then(() => res.json({ success: true }));
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ postnotfound: 'No post found' }));
    });
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

I used the following code to prevent dublicated on addition.

```
   if (
                word.filter(
                  wrd =>
                    wrd.ugrWordCyr.toString().toLowerCase() ===
                    req.body.ugrWordCyr.toLowerCase()
                ).length !== 0
              ) {
                return res
                  .status(404)
                  .json({ wordalreadyexists: 'Word already exists' });
              } else {
                const newWord = new Word({
                  user: req.user.id,
                  ugrWordCyr: req.body.ugrWordCyr,
                  rusTranslation: req.body.rusTranslation,
                  example: req.body.example,
                  exampleTranslation: req.body.exampleTranslation,
                  origin: req.body.origin,
                  sphere: req.body.sphere,
                  lexis: req.body.lexis,
                  grammar: req.body.grammar,
                  partOfSpeech: req.body.partOfSpeech,
                  style: req.body.style
                });
```

What code should I write to do the same on update?

Comment: Mongo can do the check for you. When you set the ugrWordCyr to be unique mongo will return an error if you try to create a duplicate. See indexes https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: how is this related to React?

Comment: I was trying to implement it with createIndex but could not understand how it works.

Comment: create index and set unique as true.

Comment: Could you show me, please using my code? I will try it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before executing `Word.findByIdAndUpdate()`, you can do a check to see if the text in `req.body` matches any existing words in your database.

```
// @route  Put api/words/:id
// @desc   Update a word by id
// @access Private

router.put(
  '/:id',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const { errors, isValid } = validateWordInput(req.body);

    // Check validation
    if (!isValid) {
      // Return any errors
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }

    Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id }).then(profile => {
      Word.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(word => {
          // Check for word owner
          if (word.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
            return res
              .status(401)
              .json({ notauthorized: 'User not authorized' });
          }

          const wordID = req.params.id;
          const wordInput = req.body;

         //find all words
          Word.find()
              .then((allWords) => {
                  //create an array of strings using each word ("apple", "apricot", ...etc)
                  const wordStrings = allWords.map((word) => word.ugrWordCyr) //not sure if thats the property that has the word-spelling

                  //check if user input already exists in all words
                  if(wordStrings.includes(req.body.ugrWordCyr)){
                       return res.status(400).json({ error : "word already exists" })
                  }

                  // Update
                  Word.findByIdAndUpdate(
                      { _id: wordID },
                      { $set: wordInput },
                      { returnOriginal: false },
                      (err, word) => {
                          if (err) {
                             console.log(err);
                          }
                      }).then(word => {
                           res.json(word);
                      });

               })
               .catch((errors) => {
                   return res.status(400).json({ errors: "could not find any words" })
               })

        })
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nowordfound: 'No word found' }));
    });
  }
);
```

Alternatively, you could also update your `Word` model and use the `unique` property when setting up your mongoose schema. I imagine your schema looks something like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

    const wordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
      },
      ugrWordCyr: { type: String, unique: true}, <-- set unique to true
      rusTranslation: { type: String },
      example: { type: String },
      exampleTranslation: { type: String },
      origin: { type: String },
      sphere: { type: String },
      lexis: { type: String },
      grammar: { type: String },
      partOfSpeech: { type: String },
      style: { type: String }
    })

const Word = mongoose.model("Word", userSchema)

module.exports = Word
```

Now when you use `findByIdAndUpdate()`, it will not complete unless you pass in a new/unique string to `ugrWordCyr` or whatever you use as the explicit word.

```
      Word.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { _id: wordID },
        { $set: wordInput },
        { returnOriginal: false },
        (err, word) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
        ).then(word => {
             res.json(word);
          });
         .catch(err => {
             return res.status(400).json({ error: "could not update word" })
          })
       })
```

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for your suggestion, I have tried it, apparently, it does not work. I am not sure what.

Comment: @NZMAI darn, maybe try the second part of my answer, we just need to modify you user model to set one of the main properties in your schema to unique.

Comment: @NZMAI awesome you're welcome and that is great to hear! Would you please consider marking my solution as the correct answer :)

Comment: How can I make it not case sensetive? I mean if words match regardless their cases they should not sneak into the DB.

Comment: @NZMAI I dont think mongoDB checks for case-sensitvity. This is something you would handle on the server-side. What you could do is modify the string in your wordInput object after defining it. You can explicitly change the input to a lower-case word. Let's say your wordInput object looks like { ugrWordCyr: "Woof" } Then just use wordInput["ugrWordCyr"] = wordInput.ugrWordCyr.toLowerCase()    That would force the desired property to be lowercase before we use the entire object in findOneAndUpdate()